# What is the endpoint address of my web service deployed on Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, soap

I am working with some code I didn't write. It is a web server deployed in Tomcat. I finally got the server up and running, but now I can't figure out what endpoint to call to get a response. Where can I find this info?

I know tomcat is running on port 9090 from inspecting the server in eclipse.

Here is the seemingly relevant portion of my `sun-jaxws.xml`

```
<endpoint name="DMS"
implementation="<path to class that implements the service>"
url-pattern="/services/ExternalDocumentService">
```

Here is part of my `web.xml`

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is a screenshot of the server info in eclipse

[image]

I already imported the WSDL into SoapUi, but I need to know what address to enter to actually reach my endpoint. Where can I find that address?

Comment: This should be something like http://localhost:9090/WAR_NAME/services/ExternaDocumentService 
You need to replace WAR_NAME by the name of the deployed web app on your Tomcat (which should be indicated on your Deployment tab when you double click on your server in Eclipse)

Comment: @DamCx Thanks for the help. I don't see the WAR name in eclipse. I see "Server Path" and "Deploy Path" and "Server Name". I will post a pic of the server info tab.

Comment: On the page you linked, there are another tab on it, which will tell you the name of the deployed resource on your tomcat server

Comment: @DamCx what tab?

Comment: At the bottom of the Overview page, you have a "Module" tab, in which you have the list of modules deployed on your server and the path which it is deployed on. It is that path that you need to replace WAR_NAME with

Comment: @DamCx I don't have that =o maybe I am running a different version or something

Comment: So have you tried 2x /services?